# How come my code works when stepping through it, but doesn't when it's running normaly?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am making an EPOS system for a school project, everything works fine, except one thing. The code does not work more than once when running properly, however, when I step through it line by line it works without any problems. The code takes a barcode inputted into a textbox, queries the products table to find the name of the product. It then takes the date and the barcode makes a composite key to check if there has been a previous sale of that product in that day, by querying the sales table. If the entry is new it creates a new line in the database, if the entry is new it queries the sales table for the quantity, adds one to it and updates that row with the quantity +1. Any ideas to why this might be happening is greately appreciated. Here is the relevant code:

```
Sub txtBarcode_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles 
txtBarcode.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        BarcodeProcess()
    end if
End Sub

Sub BarcodeProcess()
    Dim barcode As String
    barcode = txtBarcode.Text
    SoldItems(barcode)
    txtBarcode.Clear()
    txtBarcode.Select()
    txtBarcode.Update() 
End Sub

Function SoldItems(ByRef barcode As String) 'This function takes the 
barcode and makes a record in the database with the product name, amount 
sold and date sold 
    con.Close()
    con.Open()
    Dim thedate As String = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now) 
    'Sets the date in the format day/month/year e.g. 01/02/2019
    Dim ProductBought As String = FindItem(barcode)
    'Returns the name of the the item sold
    Dim quantity As integer
    Dim test As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Product_Name FROM Sales WHERE 
    ProductID_DateSold ='" & barcode & thedate & "'", con)
    Dim numberof As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Quantity_Sold FROM Sales 
    WHERE ProductID_DateSold ='" & barcode & thedate & "'", con)
    If test.ExecuteScalar = ProductBought Then 
    'If the same product has been bought more than once in the same day 
    'then the number of items sold increases by 1
        quantity = numberof.executescalar
        quantity += 1
        Dim update As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Sales SET Quantity_Sold =" 
        & quantity & " WHERE ProductID_DateSold ='" & barcode & thedate & 
        "'", con)
        update.ExecuteNonQuery
    Else 
    'If it is the first time the product is bought that day a new row is 
    'inserted into the database
        Dim insert As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Sales 
        (Product_ID,Product_Name,Date_Sold,Quantity_Sold,
        ProductID_DateSold) VALUES ('" & barcode & "','" & ProductBought 
        & "','" & thedate & "'," & quantity + 1 & ",'" & barcode & 
        thedate & "')", con)
        Try
            insert.ExecuteNonQuery
        Catch ex As Exception
            Errors(ex.message)
        End Try
    End If
    OutputBox.Items.Insert(0, "One " & ProductBought & " has been sold.")
    OutputBox.Update()
    con.Close()
    Return nothing
End Function

Function FindItem(byVal barcode As String)
    con.Close()
    Dim name As String
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Product_Name FROM Products WHERE ProductID = '" & barcode & "'", con)
    Try
        con.Open()
        name = da.ExecuteScalar
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return name
End Function
```

Comment: The thing to do in this case is to add some tracing code, i.e. some code that will output the state without your having to step and examine it that way. That means that you can get a look at what's happening without breaking into the debugger and hopefully see it when it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Note that you can output to a file if desired but probably just use `Debug.WriteLine` or `Console.WriteLine` and see it in the Output window. Using `Debug.WriteLine` means that you can leave the code in and it will be automatically ignored on a Release build but I've noticed that output from `Console.WriteLine` seems to appear more immediately than for `Debug.WriteLine`.

Comment: Can you provide details on "doesn't work"? Does it throw an error? Does it give results you didn't expect?

Comment: Oh sorry yeah. I included pictures but forgot had to take them down. Basically if I run the code line by line it would successfully query the database and get the product name and be able to update it. If I run it normally it woks the first time and then the rest of the time it just retrieves a blank value from the database